# Get the latest file in a folder from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to get the latest file in a folder.
I have the following files
in a folder

```
A1.txt
A2.txt
A3.txt
A4.txt
A5.txt
```

I need to get the latest file ie `A5.txt`

i am using the following command to get the latest file.

```
SET @c = 'dir  /b /o-e ' + QUOTENAME(@Path, '"') + ' A%.txt'  
INSERT INTO #f (Filename)   EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @C
```

This will populate all the files to a temp table.
I will take the top 1.

is there any simple method to take the latest file

The folder contains doc file also,but i need to take the file startingwith A

Comment: Use C# (e.g. CLR or not doing this in your stored procedure in the first place) or PowerShell for this. Trying to parse this from xp_cmdshell output is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: I am looking a solution in stored procedure

Comment: Your method is reasonable.  Presumably, you will be doing a lot more processing on the file.  So, I wouldn't worry if this step seems inefficient, since the next step will probably take much longer.